# Trigger workflow when Event created only if parent object is an Opportunity?

Tags: workflow

I'd like a workflow that sends an email whenever a new Task or Event is created on an Opportunity, but NOT if the a Task or Event is created on an Account or a Contact etc.

Is this criterion possible to implement? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the WhatID you can know whether the activity created on account or opportunity.

WhatID refers to object type things.  That would typically be an Account ID or an Opportunity ID

> You can set like WhatID would be 006

Or startswith 006

Add your custom requirements if you need anything

Comment: Thanks. I found that all Opps start with id '001' and went with BEGINS(WhatId,'001') in my workflow criteria.

Comment: @finisterre Actually the prefix '001' refers to Accounts. As the answer correctly states, Opportunities begin with the prefix '006'.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. It turns out I actually wanted to do it for Events and Tasks on Accounts. Typo in my first comment.